# Is there any way to make a reset button for this in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a reset button for this, can anyone help me, i think it's kinda right but i don't really know how this works. And the reset button doesn't show up on the screen which is confusing for me

```
from tkinter import *

# Create the Counter
counterCheck = 0


# Functions
def checkClick():
    global counterCheck
    counterCheck += 1
    textClick.config(text=counterCheck)



def ResetButton():
    global counterCheck
    counterCheck = 0
    textClick.config(text=counterCheck)


# The Display
root = Tk()
root.title("Left Click / Spacebar Counter")
textClick = Label(root, width=1600, height=3, text=0, font=("Courier", 44))
textClick.pack()
ClickCounter = Button(root, width=1600, height=600, text="Click Here", command=checkClick)
ClickCounter.bind("<space>", checkClick)
ClickCounter.focus_force()
ClickCounter.pack()
ResetB = Button(root, width=1600, height=100, text="Click Here to Reset", command=ResetButton)
ResetB.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **tkinter**, the **height and width** of a button are on **character units**, specifically the height and width of the number 0. The height of your widgets are pushing the reset button off the screen.

This code should work better:

```
from tkinter import *

# Create the Counter
counterCheck = 0

# Functions
def checkClick():
    global counterCheck
    counterCheck += 1
    textClick.config(text=counterCheck)

def ResetButton():
    global counterCheck
    counterCheck = 0
    textClick.config(text=counterCheck)

# The Display
root = Tk()
root.title("Left Click / Spacebar Counter")
textClick = Label(root, width=10, height=1, text=0, font=("Courier", 44))
textClick.pack()
ClickCounter = Button(root, width=20, height=1, text="Click Here", command=checkClick)
ClickCounter.bind("<space>", checkClick)
ClickCounter.focus_force()
ClickCounter.pack()
ResetB = Button(root, width=20, height=1, text="Click Here to Reset", command=ResetButton)
ResetB.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Output

[image: Counter]

Comment: Oh my god Thank you so much youre the best